# Traceroute -- where does it end when user is SSHed?

Tags: ssh, networking, traceroute

When you traceroute a user SSHed into a server, does the traceroute end with the server or the computer of the person SSHing?

Or is the answer more nuanced?

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, please try to clarify it.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Really? It seemed quite simple: when I run a traceroute on a... let's say webserver IP to make it even simpler... if someone is SSHed into that server running commands, am I going to find the IP for the computer of the person running the commands, or for the server they're running them from? Though that's over-simplifying things a bit and might lead to quibbling.

Comment: You don't understand how `traceroute` works.  See [here](http://www.slashroot.in/how-does-traceroute-work-and-examples-using-traceroute-command)  (first hit on Google).

Answer (score 3):

When you trace route from the server via ssh or to the user logged on the server via ssh, you trace the server, because it's responsive to the connection created.
You have no way to know the IP of a person connected on SSH, nor even whether there is a person connected on SSH.

Cheers,

Comment: There must be a way. It's just ports and IPs ( semi-ironic winky: ;o) ). Though I appreciate this does *kind of* answer my question. Just without the nuance.

Comment: @AmyTMcBride There is no nuance. The fact that a user may be logged in over SSH is neither relevant nor apparent from the server's IP address.

Comment: @hschou That's something at least hshou. Thanks. Much better than this answer, which doesn't help me or anyone else at all. Just wish I could still vote down. Stupid losing my old account :( :( :( :( :( :(.

Comment: @AmyTMcBride Of course you can't. You'd need to have access to data on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your question is ambiguous. You do not say from where you are issuing the trace, or which IP your are tracing.

But I think that you are saying that you are logged into the server, and you are tracing a SSH user's IP address, who is logged into the same server. Then yes, you will receive the route from your server to that user's IP address. But the route reported to you might not be the same route that he/she is using from his IP to your server (and likely won't be).